# Dynamically load TabItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 xaml files: MainWindow.xaml and Subscreen.xaml.

I want to dynamically load Subscreen.xaml as a TabItem under TabControl of MainWindow.xaml.

There are a ViewModel for each View.

- MainWindow.xaml: MainViewModel
- SubScreen.xaml: SubViewModel

The following is the test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest2()
{
    // Arrange

    // Initilize a subVM of CMSEditorViewModel type
    var subVM = new SubViewModel();

    // Initialize a mainVM of CMSEditorMainViewModel type
    var mainVM = new MainViewModel();

    // Initialize a MainWindow of DynamicCMS.Exe.CMSEditor
    var mainWindow = new MyEditor.MainWindow();
    mainWindow.DataContext = mainVM;


    ContentPresenter presenter = new ContentPresenter();
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(CmsPath.DirViewWithBS + "Subscreen.xaml"))
    {
        DataTemplate template = XamlReader.Load(stream) as DataTemplate;
        presenter.ContentTemplate = template;
        presenter.Content = subVM;
    }

    // Create a TabItem of TabControl                
    TabItem item = new TabItem();
    item.Header = "Tab1";
    item.Content = presenter;
    item.Name = "tab1";

    // Get "mainTabControl" TabControl from MainWindow
    CustomTabControl tab = CmsUtil.GetControl((Visual)mainWindow.Content, "mainTabControl") as CustomTabControl;

    // Add TabItem to TabControl
    tab.Items.Add(item);

    // Act
    CustomTabControl customTabControlEditor = (CustomTabControl)CmsUtil.GetControl((Visual)mainWindow.Content, "EditTabControl");

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(customTabControlEditor);
}
```

The "mainTabControl" is defined in MainWindow.xaml -> I can get this "mainTabControl" TabControl.

The "EditTabControl" is defined in Subscreen.xaml -> I can't get this "EditTabControl" TabControl -> customTabControlEditor is null.

Is anything wrong in the code that loading dynamically?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors? What if you set tabcontrol ItemsSource property?

Comment: @Babbillumpa, Thank you for quickly reply. The above dynamically loading design is working in real application. But when I write test code that using this dynamically loading design. It is not working.

Comment: You're welcome, what's not working? Do you have any error or simply nothing is shown?

Comment: There is no any error. I only can't get "EditTabControl" control from Subscreen.xaml file.